# Transferring videos from Sony Video Camera to PC via USB connection

Tags: video, recording, camera, xvid

I have a Sony video camera (DCR-TRV340e) and loads of video tapes that I like to transfer to my PC. The camera has USB connection and I've loaded its driver with no problems.

Which video software do you recommend me to use? I want to have my videos in XviD format with maximum 1 GB for a 1 hour film. How much time does it take to do that for a 1 hour film? Should I use USB connection or another type of connection?

Detailed information about connection and software settings would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be to use the software that came with your camera, and, if the supplied program does not support the XviD format, then use a program such as [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) to convert it to whatever video format you like.

Comment: note if the software that came with the camera doesn't support XviD directly, you'll want to export the films in as high quality and native a format as it allows.  then the other conversion software has as much to work with as possible.

Comment: also note that the latest Handbrake versions no longer support the AVI container format.